# Hi, I am stuck with an error " TypeError: Invalid shape (3742, 3832, 2) for image data"

Tags: numpy, image-segmentation

I am trying to implement a smooth_blending algorithm for large image segmentation. But stuck with an error "TypeError: Invalid shape (3742, 3832, 2) for image data". I like to mention one more thing the code was first implemented with the satellite image, but I m trying to implement the same with orthomosaic. The orthomosaic is created by UAV images.

For getting an idea, code has been given below-

```
predictions_smooth = predict_img_with_smooth_windowing(
    input_img,
    window_size=patch_size,
    subdivisions=2,  # Minimal amount of overlap for windowing. Must be an even number.
    nb_classes=n_classes,
    pred_func=(
        lambda img_batch_subdiv: model.predict((img_batch_subdiv))
    )
)
```

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

`model.predict(...)` accepts a 4D tensor of shape `(batch, x, y, nb_channels)`.

Try changing the shape from the 3D you have currently to a 4D one as specified